# How do you add a .jar file to java library in Apache NetBeans 12.0

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I wanted to know how to add a .jar to the java library in Apache NetBeans 12.0 due to method having changed from previous versions (There is not a library tab available in 12.0 when you select properties). For example the previous method in NetBeans was the following:

In NetBeans, create a new project or open an existing project in which you want to add the JAR file.

Then click on the menu Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize.

The Project Properties window will open.

In the project properties window, click on the Libraries node at the left Categories pane.

Then on the right side, click on the Run tab and then click on the Add JAR/Folder button and browse the external JAR files you want to add, as shown in the below image. Then click on the OK button.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out it seems in Apache NetBeans 12.0 they moved the libraries option out of the properties tab and into the tools tab[image]